# Is there a way to center Vis.js Network to top?

Tags: javascript, vis.js, vis.js-network

Is there any way to fit Network to the top, instead to the center of the canvas?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, see:

http://jsbin.com/kurukuxeza/edit?html,output

`code`

I believe it depends on the size of your network, but that example should suffice.